# virtualbox guest addition makes the screen smaller and unresizable

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

My host is a brand new Ubuntu 22.04, my guest a windows 10, virtualbox is 6.1.32, installed with a simple `apt install virtualbox`

Without Virtulbox guest addition and with this command :

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Win10" CustomVideoMode1 1920x1080x32
```

I can reach a resolution of 1920x1080 on my windows 10 guest.

But as I need shared folder I installed guest additions CD on windows guest.

The shared folders are now accessible, but the side effect is that the resolution of my windows guest in now 1024x768 and the auto-resize does not work despite the toggle is activated in the menu.

I tried many things :

- uninstall/re-install guest addition
- uninstall/re-install virtualbox
- I saw a version 6.1.34 of virtualbox but does support ubuntu 22.04 yet
- dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
- I installed a brand new window guest from the latest ISO provided by microsoft : it has the same effect
- I installed virtulbox-guest-* on host (included x11 stuff)
- It is not possible anymore to set a hint resolution for the guest display.

Nothing is working.

I did not have such a problem with ubuntu 18.04.

Do you have an idea how can I make auto-resize work ?

Comment: Did you reboot windows after installing the guest addons? Also, you may need to change its mode from fixed to resizable through the menu. If all fails, install the guest addons once more and reboot another time as well.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to reinstall the Guest Additions. I have a Windows 10 VMware guest at 1290x900 resolution so it is not a Windows 10 limitation.

Comment: Like I wrote I already reinstalled the Guest Addition, and of course I rebooted Windows as requested by the installation program.

Comment: Maybe also try reinstalling Virtual Box and then restarting the host computer. Otherwise, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution :

I downgrade linux kernel from 5.15.0-27 to 5.15.0-25
Re-install evrything and now it is ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).